# MarkLogic: Xpath vs searches

Tags: xpath, indexing, xquery, marklogic

Consider the following Xpath expression:

```
/book/metadata/title[. = "Good Will Hunting"]
```

And the following search expression:

```
cts:search(/book/metadata, cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("title"), "Good Will Hunting"), "unfiltered")
```

Xpath will make use of the relationship indexes and the value indexes. 
Does search make use of both term list indexes and value indexes ? Which of the above queries are more efficient and scale able ?

Comment: In general in database technology asking in such a generic way what is more efficient is often more guess work. How efficient something is will also be heavily depend on how much data you have, the structure of the data, your hardware and many possible optimizations. So to get really relevant numbers, why don't you simple try it on your dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at `xdmp:plan` of each of these. This will show you exactly what questions we are sending to the index given your particular index settings. These would usually be fairly comparable, except your `cts:search` is missing the first argument. I'm assuming it would be `/book/metadata` so that you pick up those constraints in search as well. A key difference is that XPaths will always be filtered. OTOH, the main cost of that is pulling all the fragments off disk, so if you are doing that anyway in consuming the results, that won't make a huge difference unless there are a lot of false positives, or you only consume the top N results.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the glitch in cts:search, I have made the changes.